# Check to see if value exists for each date.

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am having trouble with the following:

I am trying to retrieve of referrer's to my site using Google Bigquery. I am looking at how many visits each domain provides by month from Jan 1, 2018 to Oct 31, 2018. However, I only want to be able to see the referrers that actually sent traffic each month (so if a domain sent traffic in Jan but not Feb, I want to ignore them entirely).

Is there an easy way to do this?

Query currently looks like this:

```
SELECT
FORMAT_DATE("%Y-%m", DATE(TIMESTAMP(date_time))) AS date,
NET.REG_DOMAIN(referrer) as referrer,
COUNT(*) AS VISITS
FROM `MY.TABLE`
WHERE [my appropriate segmentation]
GROUP BY DATE, REFERRER
ORDER BY REFERRER, DATE
```

I was looking into using UNNEST and array formulas, but I don't entirely understand how to use them.

Thanks in advance

Comment: A way to look at this logically is: I want to select referrers where the referrer's visits are > 0 in every month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL (quick wrap around your original query)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT DATE, referrer, VISITS
FROM (
  SELECT DATE, referrer, VISITS, COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY referrer) total_months
  FROM (
    SELECT
      FORMAT_DATE("%Y-%m", DATE(TIMESTAMP(date_time))) AS DATE,
      NET.REG_DOMAIN(referrer) AS referrer,
      COUNT(1) AS VISITS
    FROM `MY.TABLE`
    WHERE DATE(TIMESTAMP(date_time)) BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-10-31'  
    -- AND [my appropriate segmentation]
    GROUP BY DATE, referrer
  )
)
WHERE total_months = 10
ORDER BY referrer, DATE
```